# Some properties of matrices over rings

Tags: ring-theory, modules

**Problem**

(i) Let $R,T$ be division rings and $m,n \in \mathbb N$, then $M_n(R \times T) \cong M_n(R) \times M_n(T)$ and $M_m(M_n(R)) \cong M_{mn}(R)$.

(ii) If $R$ is a semisimple ring and $n \in \mathbb N$ then $M_n(R)$ is semisimple.

Using (i) I could show (ii):

Suppose $R$ is a semisimple ring, then by Wedderburn theorem there are $D_1,...,D_r$ division rings and $n_1,...,n_r$  such that $R \cong M_{n_1}(D_1) \times ... \times M_{n_r}(D_r)$. So $M_n(R) \cong M_n(M_{n_1}(D_1) \times ... \times M_{n_r}) \cong M_{nn_1}(D_1) \times ... \times M_{nn_r}(D_r)$, and again, by Wedderburn this implies $M_n(R)$ is semisimple.

I would appreciate if someone could help me to show the properties in (i).

Comment: I'm betting you can see the map to show $M_n(R\times T)\cong M_n(R)\times M_n(T)$ on your own. Can you write it in so we know you at least thought about that?

Comment: Great job solving the second part :) Thanks for including it!

Comment: You're absolutely right about being able to do that on my own, I define the map that sends $\begin{bmatrix}(r_{11},t_{11})&\cdots&(r_{1n},t_{1n})\\\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\(r_{n1},t_{n1})&\cdots&(r_{nn},t_{nn})\end{bmatrix} \to (\begin{bmatrix}r_{11}&\cdots&r_{1n}\\\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\r_{n1}&\cdots&r_{nn}\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}t_{11}&\cdots&t_{1n}\\\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\t_{n1}&\cdots&t_{nn}\end{bmatrix})$. I've already checked this map is indeed an isomorphism of rings. Now I'll read your answer for the other property and ask if I have questions, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't really have a problem with the $M_n(R\times T)\cong M_n(R)\times M_n(T)$ (or if you do, you'll probably see the solution soon for yourself.)

Hints:

If you believe that matrices can be multiplied "in blocks", then the isomorphism $M_m(M_n(R)) \cong M_{mn}(R)$ is just a reflection of that. Given an element $((a_{i,j}))_{x,y}\in M_m(M_n(R))$, you can make it into a block matrix in $M_{mn}(R)$ by sending $((A)_{i,j})_{x,y}\mapsto (A)_{xn+i,yn+j}$. However, this seems rather complex to verify if you have doubts about "block multiplication" working.

Alternatively, you could try to reason abstractly by using the fact that $M_n(R)$ is isomorphic to the ring of $R$-linear tranformations of $R^n$, $End(R^n)$. You would be arguing that for each $End(R^n)$-linear transformation of $End(R^n)^m$, you can produce an $R$ linear homomorphism of $R^{mn}$ such that the assignment is a ring homomorphism. The obvious candidate for a mapping is to let the elements of $End(R^n)$ operate on length $n$ blocks of an element of $R^{mn}$.